# Another front-end technology inqury - but using serverless backend

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, vue.js

We have started to work with serverless technologies specifically with AWS Lambda and API Gateway using the serverless framework.  We are working with Auth0 to manage authentication.  Question is what is the best front-end technology we should use?

I think that we can build the front-end using S3 and cloudfront.  The flexibility of each webpage or a set of webpages without any server sounds fantastic and simple, however I wanted to know of any pros and cons in building out web pages that use standard javascript ajax calls using S3 and cloudfront versus using other front-end technologies such as angularjs or vue?

tldr;: Should we build front-end pages using angularjs, vue, etc. or should we use S3 using pure AJAX calls?  What are the pros and cons?

Comment: You can host Angular/Vue on S3 just fine. I'm not understanding the distinction you're trying to make.

Comment: Saw the down votes - but am offering an answer below. hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion...I understand that I can host Angular/Vue on S3, the question why should I?  What are the pros/cons to using those technologies over simple javascript ajax calls?

Comment: @DavidD Again, I don't understand the attempted distinction. Vue doesn't even *make* AJAX calls natively - that's your responsibility (they even ditched the former optional vue-resource plugin: https://medium.com/the-vue-point/retiring-vue-resource-871a82880af4). You can make simple JavaScript AJAX calls in Vue just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should find hosting any application that uses a popular SPA framework via S3 is achievable. The fact you are using serverless for the API(s) that will be called from your SPA application makes no difference from the perspective of the SPA (client). The client is referencing a web endpoint only. For secured API endpoints, please look at Auth0's Resource API approach, where you would receive a JWT ID Token and JWT Access Token on successful authentication, and send the JWT Access Token with each request. More information on this on the Auth0 website together with samples illustrating how it all works.

Regarding choice on SPA framework / JS technology to use - here are a few useful links to help getting started:

- AngularJS - https://auth0.com/docs/client-platforms/angularjs
- AngularJS 2 - https://auth0.com/docs/client-platforms/angular2
- EmberJS - https://auth0.com/docs/client-platforms/emberjs
- EmberJS 2 - https://auth0.com/docs/client-platforms/ember2js
- React - https://auth0.com/docs/client-platforms/react
- jQuery - https://auth0.com/docs/client-platforms/jquery
- Vanilla JS - https://auth0.com/docs/client-platforms/vanillajs

Hope your project is a success.